# Checking data in a file for duplicates (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, duplicates, keyword-search

I am trying to make a list of topics for another project to use and I am storing the topics in `Topics.txt`. However, when the topics are stored in the file, I do not want duplicate topics. So when I am saving my topics to my `Topics.txt` file, I also save them to a `Duplicates.txt` file. What I want to do is create a conditional statement that won't add topics to `Topics.txt` if the topics are in the `Duplicates.txt`. My problem is, I don't know how I could create a conditional statement that could check if the topic is listed in `Duplicates.txt`. A problem may arise if you scan for keywords such as "music", seeing that "electro-music" contains the word "music".

```
Entry = input("Enter topic: ")
Topic = Entry + "\n"
Readfilename = "Duplicates.txt"
Readfile = open(Readfilename, "r")
Readdata = Readfile.read()
Readfile.close()
if Topic not in Duplicates:
    Filename = "Topics.txt"
    File = open(Filename, "a")
    File.append(Topic)
    File.close()
    Duplicate = Topic + "\n"
    Readfile = open(Readfilename, "a")
    Readfile.append(Topic)
    Readfile.close()
```

Comment: Can you add some examples and example code?

Comment: How do you store the topics? One per line?

Comment: I'm not sure a plain text file really suits your needs here. A SQLite table could have distinct enforcement and also perform keyword search

Comment: I store each topic one per line with "\n" and then strip the "\n" when I got to read the topic with my other program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read a file line by line which would result in a solution like this one

```
Entry = input("Enter topic: ")
Topic = Entry + "\n"
Readfilename = "Duplicates.txt"
found=False
with open(Readfilename, "r") as Readfile:
    for line in Readfile:
        if Topic==line:
            found=True
            break # no need to read more of the file

if not found:
    Filename = "Topics.txt"
    with open(Filename, "a") as File:
        File.write(Topic)

    with open(Readfilename, "a") as Readfile:
        Readfile.write(Topic)
```

Comment: How could this be transformed to exclude capitalized variations of the topic?

Comment: @Capattax have a look at the [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) - they can do many useful things, normally strings are compared case-sensitively (`"a"=="A"` evaluates to `False`)

Answer (score 0):

You can store your topics in a set. A set is collection of unique items.

```
topics = {'Banjo', 'Guitar', 'Piano'}
```

You can check for membership using:

```
>>> 'Banjo' in topics
True
```

You add new things to a set via `.add()`

```
topics.add('Iceskating')
>>> topics
set(['Banjo','Guitar', 'Piano', 'Iceskating'])
```

Python 3 Docs on sets [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). The tutorial page on sets is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: This is useful for checking for duplicates on one file, but I have two programs that add topics to the `Topics.txt`. The first program adds topics manually, while the other program crawls pages for topics. So if I had two sets, one set for each program, they would only add duplicates to their respective sets. They would not be able to identify duplicates from the other set.

Comment: The nice thing about a set is if you have duplicates in your original data it will remove them. So if you have a list `['one', 'two', 'two', 'three']` and you copy it into a set, that set will be `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

Comment: To add to this, it seems like what you're doing is at risk of being too involved to use simple .txt files to store your data. I'm going to second @cricket_007s earlier suggestion of using an SQLite table.

Comment: I used @janbrohl 's method and I was able to successfully store the topics in both files and it would not store duplicates. While storing a topic, I could also store topics containing that topic (ie. "music" and "electromusic")

Comment: @Capattax if you want to add more info to the topics either use [sqllite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) or have a look at [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) / [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)